# If an Osprey found itself unable to rotate its engines to vertical, what would be the emergency procedure for landing?

Tags: landing, emergency, v-22

Let's say an [Osprey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) appears to be flying normally in forward flight. In preparation for landing, the pilot tries to command the engines to begin tilting to vertical, but nothing happens. What now?

If there's a manual way to crank the engines up, that's not working either.

Comment: I'm not an Osprey pilot, but I'm guessing the procedure is something like "land normally" (i.e. not vertically.)

Comment: @reirab Wouldn't the props hit the ground?

Comment: I suspect "fasten your seatbelts" would feature strongly in the emergency landing procedure.

Comment: @RyanBurnette Ah, looks like you're right. I didn't realize the blades were long enough to touch the ground, even with the prop mounted so high, but it looks like they are. This might be useful information to add to the question.

Comment: @reirab That was the purpose of the question. When an Osprey is in forward flight, the propeller disk's lowest point is significantly lower than the extended landing gear. That's why I was wondering what the procedure is if the Osprey can't get it up. I apologize for not being more specific about the V-22's design.

Comment: @HowardMiller Yeah, I figured out that that was the purpose after I looked at a diagram and saw that the props would indeed strike the ground. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Bell Helicopter [V-22 Guidebook](http://www.bellhelicopter.com/MungoBlobs/126/268/V-22%20Guidebook%202013_update_PREVIEW_LR2.pdf) covers survivability in Appendix 1.

Specifically it refers to

> Redundant Fly-by-Wire Controls
>
> Redundant Electrical Power
>
> Redundant Hydraulics Swashplate
>
> Actuator Armor

implying that this possibility has been engineered to a minimum.

Nevertheless, the premise of your question is that it's occurred, so further on in the same section we see

> V-22 crashworthiness is a function of design. Heavy components,  such
> as the engines and transmissions, are located away from  the cabin and
> cockpit area. **The proprotors are designed to fray or  “broomstraw”
> rather than splinter on impact with the ground**. The  energy-absorbing
> landing gear system is designed to attenuate  most of the energy for
> hard landings up to 24 fps. The wing is  constructed to fail outboard
> of the wing/fuselage attachment in a  manner that absorbs kinetic
> energy and ensures the cabin area will  not be crushed, thereby
> protecting the occupants. An anti-plow  bulkhead prevents the nose
> from digging in on impact, and the  fuselage provides a reinforced
> shell that is designed to maintain 85%  of its volume during a crash.
> Aircrew and embarked troops receive  additional protection from
> crashworthy seats that stroke vertically to  absorb energy

(my emphasis)

Since the aircraft is still flying, I'd head for the nearest decently equipped airfield, conduct a normal fixed wing approach and land, trusting that the rotors will sweep a nice clean path along the runway instead of peppering the fuselage with shrapnel. I'd probably take the precaution of cutting power early to reduce the kinetic energy in the rotors before they hit the ground.

Comment: I appreciate the information about crashworthiness of the Osprey. I'd like to ask if your description of making represents the response of an actual Osprey pilot?

Comment: I wish, but no.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because I suspect I'm not going to get a better one. I've known helicopter pilots and fixed wing pilots, and I think your answer is probably pretty accurate.

Comment: I was going to state that since the bottom swing of the props is away from the fuselage, that helps with any debris from impact. But then I found several videos of V-22s starting up, and clearly the props rotate in the OTHER direction so that any impacts are headed TOWARDS the fuselage. I wonder why...

Comment: Yeah, I think you'd definitely want to kill the power either before or immediately after touchdown and hold the nose high as long as possible. I suppose you could also adjust prop pitch to try to slow the props as much as possible, but you'd want to be careful to do this evenly and not create any weird yawing moments.

Comment: If the Osprey can pitch the whole aircraft to vertical and hover with its tail nearly touching the ground, passengers could just jump out. Then the pilot could move off and climb, return to horizontal flight, and make the crash landing. The Osprey really is a bird of a different feather.

Comment: @HowardMiller but is are an Osprey's engine powerful enough to act as if in vertical mode when in horizontal position (i.e. can an Osprey "hang by it's nose in a near-hover" )

Comment: @CGCampbell When it's operating normally, the V-22 Osprey can take off vertically, hover, and even fly backwards. This [link](http://youtube.com/watch?v=OWTOjXdSR7w) shows it hovering normally. The flight mode I'm talking about is purely my own speculation

Comment: I'm fully aware of its modes of flight, I've even been in one in flight, as an Army liaison to a USMC flight. The fact that one can hover, when the engines are in 'helicopter mode' does not mean it can hang 'on its nose' in 'airplane mode' hovering. That's all I meant.

Comment: The USAF experimented with tail-sitting VTOL aircraft in the Fifties [(Convair XFY-1)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_XFY_Pogo), but found them challenging to land. Attempting it in an aircraft not designed for it would be even more difficult. As a passenger I'd not be enthusiastic about climbing down the now vertical cargo hold only to have to fall the last twenty or thirty feet.

Comment: @DanielGriscom A possible answer to why the 'proprotots' rotate the way they do is so that when in vertical mode, the outer blade will be advancing. As the rotors spin, for part of their cycle, a given blade is moving forward faster than the V-22 is moving, while another blade will be retreating, and moving slower than the aircraft. The retreating blade doesn't have as much lift as the advancing blade, and is passing over the wing where there will be more turbulent airflow. The advancing blade acts  like an extension of the wing, generates more lift, and is moving through less turbulent air.

Comment: @HowardMiller ahhh... similar to the concept of washout: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washout_(aeronautics) . Sounds right: thanks.

Comment: This answers another question I was going to post... Given that they are used both vertically and horizontally, does the Osprey have propellers or rotors? Apparently they just smashed then together into "proprotors". 

Comment: Maybe the landing might go something like [this](https://www.facebook.com/TheBeautyOfAviation/videos/693996867449973/)

Comment: The PDF link is broken (yes, I know this answer's author won't see this, but another Stacker who might have access to the PDF somewhere else might).

Answer (score 9):

A fixed nacelle landing is an emergency procedure practised routinely in a flight simulator, however actually getting this condition is very rare to date. In short, we reduce gross weight if able, calculate a touchdown speed, fly a shallow approach, and shut down engines after touchdown on rollout.

As for "hanging on the proprotors" in airplane mode, theoretically possible at low gross weights but highly unstable. Besides violating operating limits, the swash plates are locked out in airplane mode giving you no control, not to mention the a few other systems that rely on gravity to pull down instead of back.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.se! Thanks for adding more information about these procedures.

Comment: @Creighton you answered another question I came up with later. Namely do the rotors have a collective when in hover mode. This makes it a true helicopter in that mode. I guess another question is whether the Osprey can go into autorotation.

Comment: I've seen videos of more conventional aircraft landing with a dead engine, and unable to extend the landing gear. These are two bladed engines. Just before touchdown, the pilot tries to 'bump' the prop to a more horizontal position with the engine's starter motor.

Comment: From the bit about "very rare to date", I take it that this _has_ in fact occurred?